# Call a method from a declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

my question is kinda simple but I haven't found it over here. I always find my answers over here and now I probably can't find a good match to set my search terms..

I got the following code:

```
Business businessClass = new Business();
Entity entityName = new Entity();

entityName = businessClass.find(object);
```

There is anyway to call the "find" method the of businessClass in the declaration of the entity ?

I don't know if it's better or worse but, seems to make more sense.

Thanks for your help. You guys are great ! I learn a lot with you all.

@Mr47, true, but

True, in this case there's no difference and this way is better, but, let's say that I got a Model and inside this model I need to initialize an object before because later I'll check if a variable of this entity is null or not.

I will try to explain:
My entity:

```
public class Entity1 
{
public int num {get; set;}
public int num1 {get; set;}
}
```

My model:

```
Public class viewTest : ViewDatabase
{
  public Entity1 entityTest {get; set;}

}
```

My controller:

```
public class ClassTest : Controller
{
  public ActionResult myMethod (int id)
  {
    ViewTest viewModel = new ViewTest(); 
    Business businessClass = new Business();

    viewModel.entityTest = new ViewTest()
    viewModel.entityTest =  businessClass.find(object); 
  }
}
```

as I inicialized it before, I can test if my variable num or num1 is false or not.
but if I try to call the business class method without  making new, my whole "entity test" will be null and not their attributes.

There's anyway to call my method and inicialize the object at the same line ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
Business businessClass = new Business();
Entity entityName = businessClass.find(object);
```

Comment: Omg, reviewing my questions just found this and forgot to alert you about my edit. Check back my main question, please ! Thanks !

Comment: Hi there. Do you mean that you want the viewModel.entityTest to have a valid object at all times?